# Is there a way to add options to the "Start of Day" and "End of Day" picklists?

Tags: picklist, calendar

On the "Personal Information" page, I can select my "Start of Day" time and my "End of Day" time - for example, if I want my day to start at 08:00 and my day to end at 20:00, I can select these options and the changes will be reflected in my  Calendar.

However, I´d like for my SF Calendar day to start at 09:30 and end at 19:30. Is there any way to make these options available in the picklists?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Those lists are not customizable. You'll also notice some other quirks, like you can't have overnight start-end times (e.g. 22:00-06:00). You'll want to vote on [this idea](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Dq4aAAC).